# How can I make an app available without adding it to the Apple app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I want to create an iPhone/iPad application for a restaurant menu. The application works only for this restaurant. I want to install the application without uploading it in the app store.
I don't want to install the application into the devices as developer device.

What options do I have for this kind of distribution scenario?

Comment: Jailbreak? [15 chars]

Comment: Is the app meant for the employees of the restaurant or for its customers?

Comment: Hey down voters: while this maybe could be phrased better, it's a legitimate difficulty with a common use case in the iOS world. Try improving the question instead. Apple under-publicizes the best solution, which I present below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple offers two ways you can do this. (The third is jailbreaking.)

The older way, an [Enterprise membership](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). This is more designed for large organizations with an IT department:

- $300 annually
- you deploy directly to the device
- terms of the contract say: may only deploy onto devices owned by the business (and yes, they can tell if you abuse this)
- apps last 1 year, must be re-signed and re-deployed
- kinda labor-intensive and fiddly, especially if the developer and device manager are different people, or use different signing keys; really needs an MDM system to work well
- since Apple doesn't review your code, you can use private API if you want. woo hoo.

**There's a newer way, which I highly recommend: the [B2B App Store](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).**

- works with your $100 developer membership
- deployment uses Apple for hosting, doesn't expire
- needs no special software; works well with [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12)
- app is private to whoever you specify
- the business gets access by signing up for the free "[volume purchase program](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/)".

In fact, the whole process is almost exactly like a normal app store app, **except** that the app is not public. Apple reviews it, puts it in the "secret" store. Developer specifies some Apple IDs; only those Apple IDs can see the app in the store (through the volume purchase interface.) They can install it, AND/OR generate redemption codes for it (which work for anyone.) It's very slick. There's a good [2012 WWDC video about it](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=311#311) for dev program members.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Both programs require the business to have a DUNS number. This is generally not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Look at docu for Enterprise Apps. But then the restaurant needs an Apple Enterprise license, and everybody installing the app must be an employee of the restaurant.

Developper and ad-hoc apps work only for a limited time (3 months if i remember correctly).

Comment: And everybody installing the app must be an employee of the restaurant.

Comment: @Sulthan i added your comment